# Getting started with the ngComponentRouter

Tags: angularjs

I am setting up the repo that I accessed on github regarding the new angular router.

https://github.com/brandonroberts/angularjs-component-router

The directions are very straightforward

1. Clone it
2. npm install
3. run gulp

However, I am not able to get the repo up and running.

I am encountering errors on in my console.   Specifically that the angular component is not a function.

```
angular.module('app.about', []).component('about', {
 restrict: 'EA',
 template: 'About {{ vm.name }}',
 controller: AboutController,
 controllerAs: 'vm'
});
```

I am not sure what is the issue.  I am aware that teh component part is to be an object.  I changed the script tag to ensure it is 1.5 but still got the same error.

Here are the errors that I am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).component is not a function

    Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I just followed your instructions and it worked.

Comment: @AmritKahlon I will update my post to show the errors.  They are pointing at the module and the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are still seeing this, there is a known issue with Angular and beatarang which can cause this error:

- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13813

In theory if you update to the latest versions of everything this looks like it is fixed now, but it can be tricky to update Angular if you are using bower and have other components dependent on an earlier version of Angular.